# Running a program using system()

Tags: c

How can I run another program from my c program in Windows 7? I am using dev-c++. This is my code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<conio.h>    

int main( void ) {    
    int result ;
    result=system("C:\Dev-Cpp\devcpp.exe\s");    
    printf("%d",result);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: And what happens when you run the code?

Comment: Is "\s" some option for devcpp.exe?

Comment: 'C:Dev-Cppdevcpp.exes' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
1
>>>>This is my output.And thanks for quick respond. I will be careful about making question next time.

Comment: Be careful system on completion does not return the result of your program ( at least not in Linux ) http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

Comment: Plz. Give me a way by which i can solve this.>>>At least run my program correctly.

Comment: @Expo_Ashiq Is my solution below not working for you?

Comment: No bro. Actually i think it's my compiller problem. As i use dev-c++ ,it return 1. 'C:Dev-Cppdevcpp.exes' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. 1>>>       this is my output.

Comment: @Expo_Ashiq if it says ".exes" and not ".exe" then you're still not using what I've written

Comment: @Ryan Haining...Thanks bro .At last it works for me. And thanks for help.

Answer (score 9):

You will have to escape the backslashes in your call to `system()`.  I'm also not sure what the trailing `\s` is for but it's probably a mistake.  Try:

```
result=system("C:\\Dev-Cpp\\devcpp.exe");
```

the `\` character has a special meaning when it is combined with the character after it.  `\n` for example indicates a newline.  In a string literal you need to write `\\` to indicate you mean a literal backslash.

alternatively look at [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the windows API for more control of the running process, especially if you don't want to block until it finishes.